# What was this strange design for the Man In Space Soonest program?

Tags: design, space-race

The following picture shows various spacecraft design proposals for the 1958 U.S. Air Force [Man In Space Soonest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_in_Space_Soonest) program:

[image: MISS proposals]

The bottom row depicts various spaceplanes, which should not be a surprise considering that many of the companies involved were established aviation manufacturers.  The top row shows three conical designs (similar to what was finally chosen for Mercury), then a bullet-shaped capsule (like Soyuz), then *dear lord what is that?!*, and finally two spherical capsules (like Vostok).

**Are there any details on the Avco design?**

I realize that Avco later made the Apollo heat shields.  Were they *trying* to make a capsule that was 70% heat shield?

Is it [swamp gas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZF2y.jpg)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not a heat shield, but rather a steel-mesh parachute of sorts.

From [This New Ocean](https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4201/ch4-4.htm):

> ...the contractor team of Avco and Convair, which, since the Sputniks, had spent more time and money on manned satellite design than other industrial firms, presented to the Air Force a highly detailed proposal for development of a "minimum" vehicle. Featuring the "bare" Atlas, the basic "one and one-half stage" ICBM with no second stage, the Avco-Convair approach would orbit a man inside a sphere weighing 1500-2000 pounds. **The steel-mesh drag brake, a metallic, inverted parachute**, would be used for atmospheric entry.

There's more information on the [Avco project on Astronautix](http://www.astronautix.com/a/avcoproject7969.html) (grain of salt not included). If I'm understanding correctly, the drag brake would be inflated with compressed air and the induced drag would actually begin the re-entry process, rather than relying on a retrorocket! This would obviously only work at a quite low orbital altitude.